# Android Fragment to DIsplay a Item Details from Listview

Tags: android, fragment

I required a Knowledge of Fragment. Suppose If I have one view of Listview Activity, On Click of each item I want to call a fragment and display a item details on same activity. I just simply want to replace content. Can someone give me an example for this?

Comment: There are tons of way to solve this. Did you look into the `FragmentManager`?

Comment: No, please provide me some sample..

Comment: Please go through the google that How to use Fragments

Comment: please provide me any good link

Answer (score 0):

You can use this sample code to replace fragment on part of your views such as `LinearLayout` or other widgets as an view

in Your `onCreate` :

```
    myList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() 
    {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long i) 
        {
             updateFragment(position);
        }
    });
```

and `updateFragment` method:

```
public void updateFragment(int selectedItem) {
    // Getting reference to the FragmentManager
    mFragment = null;
    fts = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    switch (selectedItem) {
        case 0:
            mFragment = new FragmentOnlineCategories();
            break;
    }
    fts.replace(R.id.categoriesViewFragments, mFragment, "0");
    fts.commit();
}
```

Xml layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="#ffffff">

    <include layout="@layout/actionbar_top_linearlayout"/>
    <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/categoriesViewFragments"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            />
</LinearLayout>
```